# about vscode api for executeCommand("explorer.newFolder")

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

I want callback for after `newFolder`,

```js
executeCommand("explorer.newFolder").then(value => console.log(value))
```

but The `value` is not the value of folderName.

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed the code of the command you executed.

The `explorer.newFolder` command is defined as `NEW_FOLDER_COMMAND_ID`, and is connected with the `openExplorerAndCreate` handler. (The result is received through the handler of `CommndsRegistry`.)

The return of the `openExplorerAndCreate`is a callback function (Promise).
When i look closely inside,, if the input parameter is not `isFolder`, that is, if it is a file, a callback function is provided by the `return commandService.executeCommand(NEW_UNTITLED_FILE_COMMAND_ID);` command.\

but if it is a folder, there is no return value. That is **`undifined`**.

> in [`vscode API documentation`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)
> return type of `executeCommand()` is `Thenable<T | undefined>`. That is, in the case of the corresponding command, it is returned as `undefined`, not `Thenable<T>`. If an error is not thrown and `undefined` is returned, it can be determined that it has been normally executed.

```js
// src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileAction.ts
...
export const NEW_FOLDER_COMMAND_ID = 'explorer.newFolder';
...
CommandsRegistry.registerCommand({
    id: NEW_FOLDER_COMMAND_ID,
    handler: async (accessor) => {
        await openExplorerAndCreate(accessor, true);
    }
});
...
async function openExplorerAndCreate(accessor: ServicesAccessor, isFolder: boolean): Promise<void> {
    const explorerService = accessor.get(IExplorerService);
    const fileService = accessor.get(IFileService);
    const editorService = accessor.get(IEditorService);
    const viewsService = accessor.get(IViewsService);
    const notificationService = accessor.get(INotificationService);
    const commandService = accessor.get(ICommandService);

    const wasHidden = !viewsService.isViewVisible(VIEW_ID);
    const view = await viewsService.openView(VIEW_ID, true);
    if (wasHidden) {
        // Give explorer some time to resolve itself #111218
        await timeout(500);
    }
    if (!view) {
        // Can happen in empty workspace case (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100604)

        if (isFolder) {
            throw new Error('Open a folder or workspace first.');
        }

        return commandService.executeCommand(NEW_UNTITLED_FILE_COMMAND_ID);
    }

    const stats = explorerService.getContext(false);
    const stat = stats.length > 0 ? stats[0] : undefined;
    let folder: ExplorerItem;
    if (stat) {
        folder = stat.isDirectory ? stat : (stat.parent || explorerService.roots[0]);
    } else {
        folder = explorerService.roots[0];
    }

    if (folder.isReadonly) {
        throw new Error('Parent folder is readonly.');
    }

    const newStat = new NewExplorerItem(fileService, folder, isFolder);
    folder.addChild(newStat);

    const onSuccess = async (value: string): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const resourceToCreate = resources.joinPath(folder.resource, value);
            await explorerService.applyBulkEdit([new ResourceFileEdit(undefined, resourceToCreate, { folder: isFolder })], {
                undoLabel: nls.localize('createBulkEdit', "Create {0}", value),
                progressLabel: nls.localize('creatingBulkEdit', "Creating {0}", value)
            });
            await refreshIfSeparator(value, explorerService);

            if (isFolder) {
                await explorerService.select(resourceToCreate, true);
            } else {
                await editorService.openEditor({ resource: resourceToCreate, options: { pinned: true } });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            onErrorWithRetry(notificationService, error, () => onSuccess(value));
        }
    };

    await explorerService.setEditable(newStat, {
        validationMessage: value => validateFileName(newStat, value),
        onFinish: async (value, success) => {
            folder.removeChild(newStat);
            await explorerService.setEditable(newStat, null);
            if (success) {
                onSuccess(value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers !  But I want a callback after create the newFolder. I need. 
Which command can I use?

Comment: The callback can be used as you do. However, you cannot receive the created folderName, and if the value is undefined without throwing an error, you can only know that it was successful.
If you want to get folderName, you need to find a method other than `explorer.newFolder` command. I haven't looked for any commands, but see other vscode extensions that create folders. For example, [vscode-create-file-folder](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-create-file-folder) is searched.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use the `explorer.newFolder` command, please contribute to vscode. Since it is an opensource project, raise an issue, discuss, develop, and PR so that the callback function returns the name of the folder created when creating the folder of the corresponding command as input.